# Extras players role in Cricket game

Tags: rules, cricket

Can extras player (more than 11) in a team can play the role of a runner for a team player who is injured in a cricket test, odi or t20 game in terms of laws and rules?

Comment: I've edited your question to be more in line with SE guidance. Salutations are not required. Asking why the rules are a way is veering into opinion, whereas the first question can be answered with fact (laws/rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [Law 25 Players, substitutes, runners and practice](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/batsman-s-innings;-runners) is very clear on this:

> 25.5.2 A runner shall be a member of the batting side.

This could of course be overridden by the playing conditions for any particular tournament, but I don't believe it is for any ICC matches.

Comment: In 1st class cricket and List A cricket the sides shall consist of 11 players each.  So a substitute (12th man) can not run.  However in other cricket it occassionally happens that you may name 12 of whom 11 can bat, in which case the 12th player could be a runner.  Also concussion substitutions would allow a 12th player to run as he/she becomes part of the team